# MemSQL Weird Insert/Update Behaviour

Tags: singlestore

We are using single node MemSQL and everything was working fine but when we are trying to move our MemSQL setup to use multi node the insert/update statements are behaving very weirdly

My table structures are like below , have removed many columns , to keep it short

```
CREATE /*!90618 REFERENCE*/ TABLE `fact_orderitem_hourly_release_update` 
(
  `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `customer_login` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `warehouse_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `store_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`order_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `fact_orderitem_hourly_scale` (
  `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `order_group_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `sku_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `sku_code` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `po_type` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `store_order_id` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `bi_last_modified_on` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000',
  PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`,`sku_id`),
  /*!90618 SHARD */ KEY `sku_id` (`sku_id`),
  KEY `idx_fact_orderitem_hourly_lmd` (`bi_last_modified_on`),
  KEY `idx_fact_orderitem_hourly_ord` (`order_id`),
  KEY `idx_order_group_id` (`order_group_id`),
  KEY `idx_store_order_id` (`store_order_id`)
);
```

My Load Script :

```
mysql -h$LiveMemSQL_DB -u$LiveMemSQL_USER --password=$LiveMemSQL_PASS -P$LiveMemSQL_PORT --verbose reports_and_summary < /home/titan/brand_catalog/upsert_memsql_orl_update.sql

Contents of .SQL File :

--start of .sql file
    TRUNCATE TABLE reports_and_summary.fact_orderitem_hourly_release_update;

#Load data into staging

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/myntra/redshift/delta_files/live_scale_order_release_upd.txt' INTO TABLE reports_and_summary.fact_orderitem_hourly_release_update LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';


#Insert/Update statement  
INSERT INTO reports_and_summary.fact_orderitem_hourly_scale
(
item_id,
sku_id,
customer_login,
order_status,
is_realised,
is_shipped,
shipping_charge,
gift_charge,
warehouse_id,
city,
store_id
)
select
fo.item_id,
fo.sku_id,
fr.customer_login,
fr.order_status,
fr.is_realised,
fr.is_shipped,
fr.shipping_charge,
fr.gift_charge,
fr.warehouse_id,
fr.city,
fr.store_id
from fact_orderitem_hourly_release_update fr
join fact_orderitem_hourly_scale fo
on fr.order_id=fo.order_id
ON duplicate key update
customer_login=values(customer_login),
order_status=values(order_status),
is_realised=values(is_realised),
is_shipped=values(is_shipped),
shipping_charge=values(shipping_charge),
gift_charge=values(gift_charge),
warehouse_id=values(warehouse_id),
city=values(city),
store_id=values(store_id);
```

--End .sql file

When I trigger the above .sql through mysql command line client , it works sometimes and it doesn't many of times , and some times if I execute the same .sql file continuously 5-10 times , the updates will get effected in one of those runs , and sometimes say for example if there are 3 records with order_id 101 and status SHIPPED and we got an update in merge table say the order status has been changed to DELIVERED , ideally status of all 3 orders should be changed to DELIVERED , but only one or 2 of the rows associated with an order are getting updated but if I execute the same .sql file content through MySQLWorkbench it works perfectly fine , I may sound stupid , but this is what is happening and I am struggling from last 2 days with this weird behavior

Please find the below screen cast , where I captured this behaviour https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v2HN-n4V0MI&feature=youtu.be

Comment: I tried to repro using similar sql as above, but it didn't repro, the updates worked fine for me. I cannot use your exact sql because the schema and queries do not match, the queries have columns that are not in the schema. Can you post an exact set of schema/query where you observe the error? Also, what version are you using?

Comment: @JackChen MemSQL Version is 5.5.3 and you can find the files and scripts here to reproduce the error  https://www.dropbox.com/s/ao8viv2wzfoh8a3/memsql_insert_update.zip?dl=0

Comment: And the cluster setup am using is one master and 2 slaves r3.2xlarge instances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your staging table is a reference table, and writes to reference tables are replicated asynchronously to the cluster. This is why sometimes your updates work as expected and sometimes they don't.

You can

- wait for a bit after writing into the reference table
- make the staging table non-reference

Comment: Thanks Jack , it makes sense , will try sync replication

Comment: Thanks Jack , it makes sense , will try sync replication and the reason we made some tables reference is , the shard of fact and dimensions are not the same , so we defined all dimension tables as reference

Comment: I have created a new schema with SYNC ON and when ever I truncate reference table and reload it , we are again landing into the issue where changes to the reference table are not getting immediately effected onto leafs

Comment: Yes, apparently SYNC does not affect reference table writes, only replication for sharded tables. Unfortunately you will have to go with one of the other workarounds.

Comment: Oh ok , then it's a big problem if your dimensions are rapidly changing and it's not possible to make sure the shard key of fact and all dimensional tables the same .

Comment: For the particular case of this staging table, there may not really be an advantage to making it a reference table. If you make it a standard sharded table, it will likely have to be broadcast as part of the update query. As a reference table, you have to wait for replication. These two both move the entire table to all nodes, so they aren't so different for performance, and in fact the broadcast might be better.